# Flutter plugin error: Cannot read packageName from C:\***\AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm building a Flutter app in Android Studio with AndroidX and Kotlin support.
I added the [Google Nearby Messages API from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/google_nearby_messages_api#-installing-tab-) and try to build.

This results in the following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM T395 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':google_nearby_messages_api:processDebugManifest'.
> Cannot read packageName from C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_nearby_messages_api-0.0.15\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

If i open the Android module and run Gradle sync it gives this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot read packageName from C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_nearby_messages_api-0.0.15\android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
Affected Modules: google_nearby_messages_api
```

There's no relevant Dart-code to show.